# simple Highcharts but doesn't run

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm new in HTML and PHP. i follow the getting starts guide of Highcharts.com and i wrote the HTML file below. i save it like index2.htm, but it show me only "Before the script..." and no chart appear.
please help me.
Thanks a lot

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>                           
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
     <p>Before the script...</p>
    <script>
        $(function () { 
            var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 19]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jquery as the example you are looking at uses it. Add the jquery cdn to the head to load jquery:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See my code below:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>                           
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
     <p>Before the script...</p>
 <script>

  $(function () { 
            var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 19]
                }]
            });
        });
});


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Actually you don't need document.ready according to the documentation. It is already calling the code: "The code above uses the jQuery specific way of launching code on document ready, but this can be replace by general onready handlers." https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that you've wrapped it in an anonymous jquery function and haven't included a JQuery reference.

If you just change you're script to be:

```
 var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 19]
                }]
            });
```

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL4fnm06/) of it working